# Optimizing SQL server performance in Docker container

Tags: sql-server, performance, docker

We are having an issue with a **very slow start (and generally poor performance) of dockerized SQL server**. Sometimes it takes 5+ minutes for a fresh container to start.

We are using SQL server in docker for integration tests during our CI build and everything is running in a Kubernetes cluster.

I think the root cause is that SQL server detects the "bare metal" CPU and does not respect the fact that it's running in a container with restricted resources:

```
2020-09-22 13:41:39.90 Server      SQL Server detected 12 sockets with 2 cores per socket and 2 logical processors per socket, 24 total logical processors; using 24 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required
```

However, this is not correct. We allow only a small portion of CPU (currently 2.5 CPU). I read that [number of logical processors has impact on number of worker threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).

I didn't find any param how to change the number of worker threads or the number of logical processors dedicated for the SQL server. The only param I found is for memory (`MSSQL_MEMORY_LIMIT_MB`). I'd like to do something similar for the CPU.

Does anyone have an idea how to run a SQL server in Docker with limited resources? Let's say 2 Gi of RAM and 2 CPUs at max (we need to scale our builds)? Is it even possible?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Does this help? https://dbafromthecold.com/2017/10/04/limiting-resources-available-to-containers/

Comment: Thanks but it does not help.. The issue might be somewhere deeper in our heavily containerized infrastructure. I can't reliably replicate the issue. It happens only time to time.